# Race condition when generating data with a GenericInputFormat

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I'm trying Flink and wrote the following example program:

```
object IFJob {

  @SerialVersionUID(1L)
  final class StringInputFormat extends GenericInputFormat[String] {

    val N = 100
    var i = 0L

    override def reachedEnd(): Boolean = this.synchronized {
      i >= N
    }

    override def nextRecord(ot: String): String = this.synchronized {
      i += 1
      return (i % 2) + ""
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val text: DataSet[String] = env.createInput(new StringInputFormat())

    val map = text.map {
      (_, 1)
    }
    //        map.print()
    val by = map.groupBy(0)
    val aggregate: AggregateDataSet[(String, Int)] = by.aggregate(Aggregations.SUM, 1)
    aggregate.print()
  }
}
```

I am creating a `StringInputFormat` once and read it in parallel (with a default parallelism = 8). 
When I run the above program, the results vary between executions, i.e., they are not deterministic. Results are duplicated 1-8x times.

For example I get the following results:

```
// first run 
(0,150) 
(1,150)

// second run 
(0,50) 
(1,50)

// third run 
(0,200) 
(1,200)
```

The expected result would be

```
(0,400) 
(1,400)
```

Because there the `StringInputFormat` should generate 8 times 50 "0" and "1" records.

I even added synchronization to the input format, but it didn't help.

What am I missing in the Flink computation model?

Comment: So where did you specify that the InputFormat should only run with parallelism=1?

Comment: I didn't. I don't understand, why should I restrict a level of parallelism to it on this level? Or is it right to write 
```
val text: DataSet[String] = env.createInput(new StringInputFormat()).setParallelism(1).map({_,1}).setParallelism(8).groupBy(0)
```
here? (it works fine)

Comment: If you don't limit the parallelism of you're input format there will be 8 different instances of it that all create values independent of each other. Since they are different objects the added synchronization has no effect. You can freely change the parallelism of individual operations. Does what you wrote give you the expected result?

Comment: Then shouldn't the code in the question result in (0, 400) (1, 400) with a parallelism of 8?  Why does the result change with each run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you observe is the result of how Flink assigns work to an `InputFormat`. This works as follows:

1. On the master (JobManager), the `createInputSplits()` method is called which returns an array of `InputSplit`. An `InputSplit` is a chunk of data to read (or generate). The `GenericInputFormat` creates one `InputSplit` for each parallel task instance. In your case, it creates 8 `InputSplit` objects and each `InputSplit` should generate 50 `"1"` and 50 `"0"` records.
2. The parallel instances of a `DataSourceTask` are started on the workers (TaskManagers). Each `DataSourceTask` has an own instance of the `InputFormat`.
3. Once started, a `DataSourceTask` requests an `InputSplit` from the master and calls the `open()` method of its `InputFormat` with the `InputSplit`. When the `InputFormat` finished processing the `InputSplit`, the `DataSourceTask` requests a new from the master.

In your case, each `InputSplit` is very quickly processed. Hence, there is a race between DataSourceTasks requesting InputSplits for their InputFormats and some InputFormats processes more than one `InputSplit`. Since an `InputFormat` does not reset its internal state (i.e., set `i = 0`) when is opens a new `InputSplit` it will only generate data for the first `InputSplit` it processes.

You can fix this by adding this method to the `StringInputFormat`:

```
override def open(split: GenericInputSplit): Unit = {
  super.open(split)
  i = 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Fabian. Can this example https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-avro/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/api/io/avro/example/AvroTypeExample.java have the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes, I think so. That example would suffer from the same issue. A fix would be welcome :-)